# Cost per men-hour not adding up

Tags: mathematical-economics

In a company with two departments, we know the actual & budget of working hours (WH) and the labor cost (LC) of both of them. I want to compute the cost per men-hour (CPMH) and the economic impact of the actual-budget difference. Thus, I have the following formulas:

$\text{CPMH actual} = \frac{\text{LC actual}}{\text{WH actual}}$

$\text{CPMH budget} = \frac{\text{LC budget}}{\text{WH budget}}$

$\text{CPMH Impact} = (\text{CPMH budget} - \text{CPMH actual}) * \text{WH actual}$

Applying real data to it, this is how this computation looks like:

|  | WH ACT | WH BUD | LC ACT | LC BUD | CPMH ACT | CPMH BUD | CPMH impact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dpmt 1 | 1800 h | 2016 h | € 32,121.00 | € 40,320.00 | 17.85 €/h | 20.00 €/h | **€ 3,879.00** |
| Dpmt 2 | 1910 h | 1890 h | € 48,168.00 | € 42,525.00 | 25.22 €/h | 22.50 €/h | **-€ 5,193.00** |
| **TOTAL** | 3710 h | 3906 h | € 80,289.00 | € 82,845.00 | 21.64 €/h | 21.21 €/h | **-€ 1,601.10** |

All the impacts are just computed using the formula. However, if I add $3 879€$ and $-5 193€$ the result is $-1,314€$, not $-1,601.1€$.

Is there something wrong with my formulas?

**EDIT:** Thanks [tdm](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/50852/40770) and [VARulle](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/50851/40770) for your answers. We are not wondering *how* does the formula doesn't add up to the total, but *why*; from a conceptual rather than mathematical perspective. To me, it seems counter-intuitive to say that breaking the financial impact of our CPMH down into departments does not add up to the overall.

Comment: O.k., read your edit and added some explanation in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Writing out the formulas for department $1$ and $2$ gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
CPMH_1 &= \left(\frac{LCB_1}{WHB_1} - \frac{LCA_1}{WHA_1}\right)*WHA_1\\
&= \frac{LCB_1}{WHB_1}WHA_1 - LCA_1\\
CPMH_2 &= \left(\frac{LCB_2}{WHB_2} - \frac{LCA_2}{WHA_2}\right)*WHA_2\\
    &= \frac{LCB_2}{WHB_2}WHA_2 - LCA_2
\end{align*}
$$
For both departments together and substituting out we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
CPMH &=  \left(\frac{LCB_1+ LCB_2}{WHB_1 + WHB_2} - \frac{LCA_1 + LCB_2}{WHA_1 + WHA_2}\right)(WHA_1 + WHA_2)\\
&= \frac{LCB_1 + LCB_2}{WHB_1 + WHB_2}(WHA_1 + WHA_2) - LCA_1 - LCB_2,\\
&= \frac{LCB_1 + LCB_2}{WHB_1 + WHB_2}(WHA_1 + WHA_2) \\
&+ CPMH_1 - \frac{LCB_1}{WHB_1} WHA_1 + CPMH_2 - \frac{LCB_2}{WHB_2}WHA_2 
\end{align*}
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align*}
&CPMH - CPMH_1 - CPMH_2\\
&= \frac{LCB_1 + LCB_2}{WHB_1 + WHB_2}(WHA_1 + WHA_2) - \frac{LCB_2}{WHB_2} WHA_2 - \frac{LCB_1}{WHB_1} WHA_1,\\
&= LCB_2\left(\frac{WHA_1 + WHA_2}{WHB_1+ WHB_2} - \frac{WHA_2}{WHB_2}\right)
+ LCB_1\left(\frac{WHA_1 + WHA_2}{WHB_1 + WHB_2} - \frac{WHA_1}{WHB_1}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
This will usually not be equal to zero unless:
$$
\frac{WHA_1 + WHA_2}{WHB_1 + WHB_2} = \frac{WHA_2}{WHB_2} = \frac{WHA_1}{WHB_1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your formulas. It's just that the CPMH impact is not a linear function and therefore the CPMH impact of a total is not the sum of the CPMH impacts of its parts.

**ADDED after your EDIT:** From a conceptual perspective, some measures of "output", "productivity", "costs", "impact", or whatever, simply "add up" from the department level to the company level, while others don't. E.g. *number of workers* adds up, *working hours* adds up, *wage expenditures* adds up, but *wage expenditures per worker* or *output per working hour* doesn't add up. This is of course because the latter are (weighted) averages, and averages don't simply add up. E.g. if both departments pay wages of \$10 per hour, this doesn't mean that the company pays \$20 per hour. Now, your *CPMH impact* is a more complicated measure, but it contains something similar to an average, and as a consequence it simply doesn't add up. Your intuition that "financial impact" should add up might be correct for a simple measure of "financial impact" like *revenue*, but for your rather involved CPMH measure it is not.